Stacked bar plot for a DataFrame
I have a below table in a DataFrame. I want to visualize it in a stacked bar plot.



Percentage
A
B
C
D
E
F




0%
10
20
50
60
100
90


10%
89
87
65
87
89
88


50%
87
876
89
978
6
0


100%
89
78
89
89
54
34



For the above table, I want to get the stacked bar chart with x-axis as columns A,B,C,D,E,F and y-axis as Percentage Counts.
For example, x-axis column A has stacked bar with 10, 89, 87, 89 for the percentages.
I want output to be like


Since you want dummy bars, you have to craft a dummy DataFrame:
tmp = df.set_index('Percentage').T
X = np.repeat(100/tmp.shape[1], tmp.shape[1])

ax = tmp.notna().mul(X, axis=1).plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0))
ax.set_yticks(np.cumsum(X)-X[0]/2, tmp.columns)

for k, c in zip(tmp, ax.containers):
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=tmp[k], label_type='center')

Output:
[

Original answer
Set percentage as index (set_index), transpose, and plot the stacked bars (plot.bar with stacked=True):
df.set_index('Percentage').T.plot.bar(stacked=True)

Output:

If you want to group by percentage, skip the transpose and use barh:
df.set_index('Percentage').plot.barh(stacked=True)

Output:


percentage should be 0%, 10%, 50%, 100% and x-axis should show the values of columns A,B,C,D,E,F with the relevant values.

@testenthu what you want is unclear, please provide a mockup/schematic of the expected graph as edit to your question

"I want to get the stacked bar chart with x-axis as columns A,B,C,D,E,F and y-axis as Percentage Counts. For example, x-axis column A has stacked bar with 10, 89, 87, 89 for the percentages." -> this seems to match the above graph. A,B,C,D,E,F as x-axis, stacked counts as Y-axis.

I added a second option, but this doesn't really match the description in the question. Please clarify.

In the above 1st option, I want percentage as y-axis label and add actual counts on the bar's.

@testenthu got it, that wasn't obvious. See update
